# how to set dropdown arrow in spinner with background?

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, android-drawable

I have dropdown with black Background, blue outline of spinner, How to put arrow image in dropdown?

I am using

> android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"

but that will remove my current background i.e. black background with blue outline. For that I am using a drawable

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp"  android:color="#405999"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this,

Create `spinner_bg.xml` file in drawable folder, then copy and paste the following

**spinner_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><layer-list>
            <item><shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#504a4b" />

                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape></item>
            <item ><bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_holo_dark_am" />
            </item>
        </layer-list></item>

</selector>
```

Inside `values` folder and `styles.xml`, add these lines

```
<style name="spinner_style" >
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
            <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>

        </style>
```

Add this style to your spinner in xml file

```
       <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:popupBackground="#cccccc" />
```

Comment: android:src="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_holo_dark_am" this is showing error

Comment: You need to add that `spinner_ab_default_holo_dark_am` image to drawable. Or else add any of your image instead of it. It should be like,  `android:src="@drawable/yourImage"`

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
09-02 11:59:26.366: E/AndroidRuntime(336):

Comment: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-02 11:59:26.366: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-02 11:59:26.366: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-02 11:59:26.366: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-02 11:59:26.366: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: @Aniruddha: Can we change the size of Bitmap using set width and height ?